# tar.gz unpacking - file: data?

Tags: bash, tar

I backed up my photo collection some time ago.
I don't really know the command I used back then.
I only know that I have a bunch of .tar.gz files, as they were splitted per gb.

I did

```
cat pictures.tar.gz* > pictures.tar.gz
```

and then

```
tar xvfz pictures.tar.gz
```

output:

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

but this fails: it says it is not a gzip file
I then tried renaming it, and bypass the gzip

```
tar xfv pictures.tar.gz
```

but this too fails.

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

then I did

```
file cat_pictures.tar.gz
```

output:

```
cat_picture.tar.gz: data
```

How to unpack?

Comment: Your problem is the "cat pictures.tar.gz* > pictures.tar.gz" command. You need to cat them in the same order that they were split. The wildcard does not guarantee that order.

Comment: Are you sure your first command was `cat pictures.tar.gz* > pictures.tar.gz`? Perhaps it was `cat pictures*.tar.gz > pictures.tar.gz`... Anyway, that command concatenates all the files in one. If you no longer have the original files, it will be very tricky to separate these. Do you still have these?

Comment: Are you able to `gunzip` each file and then `tar -x` each "gunzipped" file one by one?  If that works, use a loop to process them all one by one.

Comment: You executed `cat pictures.tar.gz* > pictures.tar.gz`. If you already had a file `pictures.tar.gz` in that dir, then it was overwritten, and probably not with all the data that existed in the file before you started AND of course it has all the other `pictures.tar.gz*` in there too. All advice above sounds worth trying. Good luck!

Comment: @GambitSupport: this is not wath the [bash reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-pathname-expansion-95) -> 3.5.8 Filename Expansion. thx for the help

Comment: @PierreFrançois: I still do have the original files. I reran the command, just to be sure, without progress.

Comment: @Nic3500: gunzipping one by one does not work.                              gunzip test.tar.gz 

gzip: test.tar.gz: not in gzip format

Comment: You did not say what the naming was of your partial files (and probably assume that we know). Only a ls -l of all files will be able to diagnose (assuming the fragments were not touched after creation).

Comment: The exact name of your files is not clear for us. You speak sometimes about pictures.tar.gz and sometimes about cat_pictures.tar.gz. I fear that you are mixing input and output files. It is also wise to separate the directories containing input and output files when you run commands with wildcards.

Comment: @GambitSupport : You are right. Because I tried different things to concantate the files. 7z and cat, is started to add cat_ or 7z_ before. files are called pictures.tar.gz.aa up to pictures.tar.gz.jr. About the crucial one, pictures.tar.gz, I'm not sure anymore whether it existed or not. If it did, I will have overwritten it.

Comment: @PierreFrançois see answer above.

Comment: @pepe456: Is your problem still not resolved?

Comment: @PierreFrançois: nope. All tips are welcome

Comment: Don't assume that you can just concatenate a bunch of `*.gz` or `*.tar.gz` files and get anything meaningful.

Answer (score -2):

Since you still have access to the original files, supposing all your pictures are in a directory called **~/Pictures/MyCollection**, or in a subdirectory of this latter, I suggest you to archive recursively and compress all the files in one operation as follows:

```
tar pczf pictures.tar.gz ~/Pictures/MyCollection
```

This will create the archive file in the current directory.

To extract the archived files, you will have to issue, in the same directory where the archive file stays:

```
tar xzf pictures.tar.gz
```

This will put the files back where they were at the moment of archiving.

So, you avoid to concatenate files manually, with the risk of mixing input and output files.

See a good tutorial [here](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/linux-tar-command/).

Comment: When saying I  have the original files, I meant I had the original tar.gz files, not the original pictures. Restoring those is what I want to do. I know how tar works, and have used it already a couple of times. the problem is I can't unzip it now, because the thing is broken some how.

Comment: @pepe456: the problem is that as long we don't know exactly what you did, it will be hard to figure out what to do for helping you. As far as I understand, at a certain moment, you concatenated **.tar.gz** files and now you try to separate these. If this assumption is correct, then a possible option is to look for the magic number in the beginning of each **.gz** file in your concatenated file. That magic number is two bytes long and is **0x1f8b**.

Comment: @pepe456: Do you have the concatenated tar.gz file (singular) or each of the tar.gz files (plural, i.e; before concatenation)? If you still have the files (plural), probably you can unzip each one of these. What is the output of: `file pictures.tar.gz*`?